# Show Validations Errors To user in identityserver4

Tags: identityserver4

i'm using IdentityServer4 with .net core 2 and i want to show error messages like invalid scope or invalid client that are shown in console to user in my /error page so that they can correct their request...how i can access failed request logs?

Comment: you can implement logger functionality.
ref link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-2.1

Comment: I wonder what your project looks like. If you are talking about an implementation of IdentityServer where you want to show this information then take a look at the samples: https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Samples Otherwise, can you explain what the design looks like?

Comment: @Ruard van Elburg  in my project agents can create a client and users that register in my service can log in in the agents service using their account in my serivce...so after they create a client they should be able to get an access token and they are having trouble with scopes and returnurls...so i want to show them their errors....

Comment: @Nilesh Vishwakarma logger only logs errors in console which i have now...i want to show users those error in my error.cshtml page....